# Are there chatbots which use AI but not machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning

I want to see the differences between two chatbots where the first one is based on AI without ML and the second one which is based on ML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very first chatbot called ELIZA was developed in 1966, so way before machine learning. It was based on pattern matching and substitution, so very limited range of answers, but still a chatbot.

If you're confident with python you could try this [implementation](https://github.com/wadetb/eliza)